# Are tf.spectral.dct and scipy.fftpack.dct equivillant?

Tags: python-3.x, tensorflow

I have compared tensorflow.spectral.dct with scipy.fftpack.dct using the following example:

**in scipy:**

```
from scipy.fftpack import dct
import tensorflow as tf

xx=np.linspace(0,3,3)
x_dct=dct(xx,2,norm='ortho')
print(x_dct)
```

array([  2.59807621e+00,  -2.12132034e+00,  -1.81298661e-16])

**in tensorflow:**

```
x= tf.placeholder(tf.float32, shape=(1,3))
x_dct=tf.spectral.dct(x,2, norm='ortho')
x_dct=tf.squeeze(x_dct)
sess=tf.Session()
sess.run(x_dct,{x:xx})
```

array([  2.59807611e+00,  -2.12132001e+00,   2.92001914e-07], dtype=float32)

The low energy coefficients are not equal.
It seems having different low energy coefficinets does not matter so much.

Answer (score 1):

I'm the author of `tf.signal.dct`. It is designed to be equivalent to `scipy.fftpack.dct`, but there are minor numerical differences between them at the moment. I believe your example is computing the fftpack DCT in `float64`, while `tf.signal.dct` only supports `tf.float32` at the moment (I plan to fix that). There is also a minor issue with `tf.signal.rfft` (which `tf.signal.dct` is implemented in terms of) where its 0th coefficient is not zero. I believe that when both of these issues are fixed the difference you're seeing in the low energy coefficients will get much smaller.

Sorry for not responding to this post sooner!

Comment: Are the issues mentioned above fixed in latest version of TF2? Also, are backend c++ libraries same in both cases. I find tf.signal.dct much slower than scipy.dct both on cpu and gpu.